# How do I say a calculated decimal has too many decimal places?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to craft an appropriately worded error message for an application I'm working on.

It boils down to when a calculated value results in having too many decimal places it can't be correctly calculated by the application.

My initial thought for an error message would be something like

```
Decimal too large to be calculated accurately.
```

I'm trying to convey the `too large` to mean a fraction with to many decimal places. But obviously `to large` means something else. **What would the correct term be?**

For a more literal example; when `0.0017985611510791366` is used in the program it throws an error. When `0.002` is used it doesn't.

Comment: Start by using two `o`'s in too. What is wrong with _Result has too many decimals to be calculated accurately_?

Comment: Are you saying you want an error message to display when a calculated value comes up irrational like that example? Or when a long decimal is inputted? Because if a calculated value comes up irrational, depending on the application there should be ways to limit the decimal points used. Please clarify.

Comment: Originally used two `o`'s then removed one `o` thinking it was wrong. Whoops.

Comment: @fuandon It's nothing to do with irrational numbers. It's to do with just having too many decimal places, it throws an error rather than attempting a calculation that might fall prey to rounding errors.

Comment: @fuandon There are no irrational numbers shown in the question. But I agree, the question is confused. I'm struggling to get my head round the idea of how the accuracy of a calculation might be determined by the number of decimal places in an input.

Comment: @Rupe I didn't want to get into specifics but some programming languages cant represent long fractions accurately.

Comment: @Ally I think you need to start again with your thinking about precision etc. If you really want to talk about there being too many (non-zero) digits after the decimal point then you're better off being explicit about it, because it's not a normal thing to be talking about.

Comment: The way you're using "fraction" is odd. One word you might find useful in replacing it is *mantissa*. You could say "Decimal representation of mantissa is too long".

Comment: Unless you're using this application for scientific purposes, I'm honestly curious why you need to throw an error like that. I could see it being a warning that rounding has occurred, but my impression of 'error' is that the program quits the calculation afterwards. Just my professional side inquiring, sorry. Will try to answer. @Rupe True, true.

Comment: @Ally I'd think the floating-point variable types of most languages I know would be able to hold decimals with more than the necessary precision for whatever your needs might be.

Comment: Unnecessarily precise/ too precise/ over-precise. Fraction overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts guys, I think mantissa might be a bit to specific / difficult to understand for the average user :). @fuandon It's to do with calculations involving money. It's defensive coding in the sense I don't want things to continue if there's the chance an extra penny may have appeared out of thin air.

Comment: @Ally I see. [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/62948/what-can-be-done-to-programming-languages-to-avoid-floating-point-pitfalls) might be a good read for you then.

Comment: `Program cannot accept more than 6 digits after the decimal point`. The terminology is elementary, not scientific, but sometimes that's what you want in an error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

> Maximum precision exceeded in calculation

?

Of course that would imply you're using some arbitrary precision level in your application. If you have questions about the language you're using and the level of precision, perhaps try StackOverflow?

A few of @Rupe's suggestions were good too.

Comment: I have to express that I really like this sentence. (:

Comment: This describes the situation perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the engineering disciplines, the error of specifying more digits than is warranted is known as "***overprecision***".

Per [Wikipedia's article on false precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision):

> Overprecision (false precision, fake precision, misplaced precision and spurious accuracy) occurs when numerical data are presented in a manner that implies better precision than is actually the case; since precision is a limit to accuracy, this often leads to overconfidence in the accuracy as well.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine when you use an application and you get an error message. You (or most) want it short, sweet, and to the point... besides, you may not even read the whole thing word-for-word.

Keeping in mind that the more "precise" a number/fraction, the more decimal places it will have.
Use statements with buzz words:

- Max precise value is not to exceed the nearest 100th (x.xx). Edit precise value to refelct fewer decimal places.
- Decrease decimal value to the nearest 100th
- Maximum decimal places exceeded. Please decrease precise value to the nearest 100th
- Fractional/numeric/precise values must only displayed to 100th place

It may be a good idea to give those a heads up that 100th place is... well.... what ever it is. I believe it is the "second" place. Maybe include an example like "remove X.XX "